# protractor proper DRY for spec

Tags: javascript, for-loop, asynchronous, protractor, dry

We have an app with a grid of rows, having Per-page SELECT and Pagination, and would like to do e2e test which does navigation and PP selection then checks the results displayed by comparing it with result from DB (pseudo-code):

```
it('should check navigation and pp', function() {
  for(i=0;i<SELECT.options;i++) {
    element(by.repeater('SELECTOR HERE(i)')).click();
    browser.wait(function which checks URL contains a segment(i));
    browser.wait(function which checks if a 'loading div is displayed');
    for(j=0;j<PagesForPP(i);j++) {
      runExpects('for pp=i'); //contains a couple expect(someElement.text).toContain(asynResult());
      element(by.css('SELECTOR(j)').click();
      browser.wait(function which checks URL contains a segment(j));
      browser.wait(function which checks 'loading div is displayed');
    }        
  }
});
```

Where function(i) is a call dependent on current Perpage and function(j)

My question is: how can we nest the two loops in a way that protractor understands (possibly executes synchronously) using protractor.promise.controlFlow() or a better way if available.

Currently, protractor ignore functions like browser.wait(function which checks URL contains a segment(i));
Which looks like so:

```
waitForPageChange: function (urlSegment) {
  console.log('>> Waiting for URL to contain: ', urlSegment);
  var currentUrl;
  return browser.getCurrentUrl().then(function (url) {
    currentUrl = url;
  }).then(function () {
    browser.wait(function () {
      return browser.getCurrentUrl().then(function (url) {
        if (urlSegment) {
          return url.indexOf(urlSegment) >= 0;
        }
        return url !== currentUrl;
      });
    });
  });
}
```

And the e2e test completes before the expects are valid (ex: we're in page 1 and we're already reaching the 2 and 3 page checks => all tests fail because they're checking incorrect values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `waitForPageChange` approach should work, I think.  I believe you're missing a "return" (from the browser.wait), so the final `then` in the function (which is the return value of the whole function) isn't the right promise.  Try this:

```
waitForPageChange: function (urlSegment) {
  console.log('>> Waiting for URL to contain: ', urlSegment);
  var originalUrl;
  return browser.getCurrentUrl().then(function (url) {
    originalUrl = url; // XXX this is racy, the page may have changed already
  }).then(function () {
    return browser.wait(function () { // this line was missing a 'return'
      return browser.getCurrentUrl().then(function (url) {
        if (urlSegment) {
          return url.indexOf(urlSegment) >= 0;
        }
        return url !== originalUrl;
      });
    });
  });
}
```

Note that code that does `return muble.then(...).then(function() {return x; })` ends up return the promise from the *last* `then` in the chain.

Also, beware of the default case where urlSegment is not provided.  You can't be sure the "originalUrl" gets initialized quickly enough.  The browser could've moved on before you load that.  To be reliable you probably want a separate "waitForPageToLeave(x)" that waits for the URL to change away from the provided one, and you should expect the caller to lookup that "original" URL before they make any changes.  (And that would be separate from a "waitForPageToGoTo(x)" function that wait for the URL to become the given one.)